# how to get consistent behavior when aggregating multiple dtypes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I am using pandas 0.20.2.

I am getting inconsistent results when aggregating a mixed dtype dataframe.
Here are some example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('20100201', periods=10,     
freq='5h3min'),columns=['Start'])
df.loc[:,'End']=df.loc[:,'Start']+pd.Timedelta(4,'h')
df.loc[:,'Value']=42.0
df.loc[:,'Dur']=df.loc[:,'End']-df.loc[:,'Start']
```

I want to apply some functions to both `Dur` (`float`) and `Value` (`np.timedelta64`).
In particular, combining `np.nansum` and `np.nanmax` I get the following:

```
**df.resample('1D',on='Start')['Dur','Value'].agg([np.nansum,np.nanmedian])**
Out[16]: 
            Value          
           nansum nanmedian
Start                      
2010-02-01  210.0      42.0
2010-02-02  210.0      42.0
```

The columns 'Dur' is **silently** ignored and dropped, whereas if apply only 
`np.nansum` I obtain the expected result including both columns

```
f.resample('1D',on='Start')['Dur','Value'].agg([np.nansum])
Out[17]: 
                Dur  Value
             nansum nansum
Start                     
2010-02-01 20:00:00  210.0
2010-02-02 20:00:00  210.0
```

How to get the same when applying `nanmedian` ? Or how to get all the expected columns in the multi-level dataframe returned at * ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [Yakym Pirozhenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4585963/yakym-pirozhenko) is correct, the error is due to the application of `np.isnan` on a timestamp column inside the function `np.nanmedian`

To avoid this, you can define your own `nanmedian` that will apply np.median on non-null timestamps:

```
def mynanmedian(x): 
    return np.median(x[pd.notnull(x)])

df.resample('1D',on='Start')['Dur','Value'].agg([np.nansum,mynanmedian])
# out:
            Dur                     Value
            nansum   mynanmedian    nansum  mynanmedian
Start               
2010-02-01  20:00:00    04:00:00    210.0          42.0
2010-02-02  20:00:00    04:00:00    210.0          42.0
```

Comment: thanks. I think this will work. if I use .apply with raw=True will the solution, especially the call to , pd.isnull, will work?

Comment: i don't know, probably not, why don't you try it out and let me know.

Comment: sure will do. I am on a smartphone at the moment:) will followup later

Answer (score 2):

`np.nanmedian` calls `np.isnan` which is not defined on datetime objects (instead one should use `np.isnat`). So pandas defaults to ignoring the column since the function cannot be called.

If you want an explicit error you could use

`df.groupby(...).agg({c: [np.nansum, np.nanmedian] for c in cols})`